# custom tableviewcell inside custom tableviewcell

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I created main table view be using custom cell. Now, I want show table view inside main table view cell.Also, Inner tableview need custom cell. Now I show table view inside a cell. but i don't know, how to create custom cell for inner table view. Kindly help me to solve this problem

Comment: as you created custom cell for parent cell obviously. what problem u are getting

Comment: how to add nib file in main table view cell?

Comment: // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: thank u baddy. it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to load nib where ever you want. For cell use this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BDCustomCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"yourCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}

return cell;
```

}

hope it helps